# xml2json return 1 object from array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, xml, xml-parsing

I'm using xml2json library in nodeJs. I have got xml:

```
<SchedulingModel >
  <Jobs> 
    <Job Id="1">
      <Operations>
      </Operations>
    </Job>
  <Job Id="2">
      <Operations>
      </Operations>
    </Job>
  <Job Id="3">
      <Operations>
      </Operations>
    </Job>
  <Job Id="4">
      <Operations>
      </Operations>
    </Job>
 <Job Id="5">
      <Operations>
      </Operations>
    </Job>
  </Jobs>
</SchedulingModel>
```

I'm trying to parse this xml:

```
const parser = new xml2js.Parser();
parser.parseString(plannerXML , (err, result) => {
      console.log(result["SchedulingModel"]["Jobs"]);
});
```

But after parsing in **result** I have just one **object** in **Jobs** array

```
console.log(result);

{ SchedulingModel: 
    Jobs: [ [Object] ] 
}
```

Who can say what's wrong?
I need all object from this xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first I noticed that you arent using [xml2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json) package, the package you are using is [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js). I tried your build and xml2js doesnt work as you imagine, it creates a single object called "Job" as an array of jobs. For a more visual test just place a stringify like this:

```
    parser.parseString(plannerXML , (err, result) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result["SchedulingModel"]["Jobs"]));
});
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes you are right, I'm using  xml2js, just I tried a lot of libraries today and forgot to remove it in example. I fond the way to use it like result["SchedulingModel"]["Jobs"][0]["Job"]. Just at this way I'm recieving array of Jobs. But any way thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

I usually use [camaro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/camaro) for transform from xml to json with easily change the desired result.

You can try with below sample (added some text to operations for example):

```
const xml = '<SchedulingModel><Jobs><Job Id="1"><Operations>a</Operations></Job><Job Id="2"><Operations>b</Operations></Job><Job Id="3"><Operations>c</Operations></Job><Job Id="4"><Operations>d</Operations></Job><Job Id="5"><Operations>e</Operations></Job></Jobs></SchedulingModel>'

const temp = {
    SchedulingModel: ['/SchedulingModel/Jobs/Job', {
        Id: '@Id',
        Operations: 'Operations'
    }]
}

const transform = require('camaro')
const results = transform(xml, temp)

console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2))
```

Response:

```
{
    "SchedulingModel": [
        {
            "Id": "1",
            "Operations": "a"
        },
        {
            "Id": "2",
            "Operations": "b"
        },
        {
            "Id": "3",
            "Operations": "c"
        },
        {
            "Id": "4",
            "Operations": "d"
        },
        {
            "Id": "5",
            "Operations": "e"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try in future!